# Execution time diff between two select queries in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Please tell the execution time difference in  sql server 2005

```
select table1.* from table1 inner join  table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

And

```
select t1.* from table t1, table t2 Where t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the SQL Server query optimiser to evaluate these in exactly the same way so you should see no difference at all in execution.

You can confirm of course by checking out the execution plans that can be generated within Management Studio.

Comment: Agreed. In addition, the better practice is to use the first form. For one, it allows you to separate join criteria from filter criteria, which makes the query easier to read for most people. It also makes it harder to accidentally get a cartesian product by leaving out the join criteria or specifying it incorrectly. It's still possible, but it's harder.

Answer (score 0):

If u rusing sql server 2005 use

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT * FROM view_Consignment_Packet_Job

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

SET STATISTICS TIME ON if use this ,u can c in message tab execution time